# How to handle URL in code behind

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm reading lists from my subsites using this code it works fine locally 
is there a better way to write this so when i upload it on another domain it wont make errors

```
         SPSite mySite = new SPSite("http://sp-prod:82/en/Colleges");

        SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb();
        SPList LstPicture = myWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Courses");


        SPListItemCollection lsts = LstPicture.Items;
        SPListItemCollection CBA = LstPicture.Items;

        course.DataSource = lsts;
        course.DataBind();
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan to use this code (I guess it is the code behind in some web part) you could write something like this:

```
using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
{
    using (SPWeb myWeb = mySite.OpenWeb())
    {
        //The list name is a good candidate for Web part property, so your code would be reusable
        SPList LstPicture = myWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Courses");
        SPListItemCollection lsts = LstPicture.Items;
        SPListItemCollection CBA = LstPicture.Items;

        course.DataSource = lsts;
        course.DataBind();
    }   
}
```

Regarding my comment for list name, you could also put siteUrl and webUrl in the web part properties.

Comment: I'm using it as a user Control